# i cannot convert this java code to javascript

Tags: java, javascript

this a program that work based on a specific algorithm. it works perfectly in java but 
whenever I run the html code i dont get error but it show me only the first three number while in java code the for loop continues until to show the whole numbers

Java code

```
 package test1;

  public class Test1
  {
  public static void main(String arg[])
   {
    int num = 1;
    counterA(num);
  }

  public static void counterA(int num)
   {       
     for (int i = num; i <= 24; i += 5)
     {
        System.out.println(i);
        counterB(i);
     }
 }

 public static void counterB(int i)
 {
    counterA(i * 3);
 }
```

### }

HTML code

```
<script>

    var num1 ;
    counterA(num1);
    var total=0;
    var counterA=function(num11)
    {
        for (num1 = num11; num1 <= 24; num1 += 5)
        {
            console.log(num1);
            counterB(num1);
        }

    }

    var counterB =function (num11)
    {
        counterA(num11 * 3);
    }
 </script>

 <body>

<button onclick="counterA(1)">Try it</button>

 </body>

</html>
```

Comment: It returns 1, 3, 9. What is the expected output?

Comment: @krnk num1 is already declared

Comment: I've executed the Java code and this returns: 1
3
9
14
19
24
8
24
13
18
23
6
18
23
11
16
21

Comment: I've created a working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jEEL4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've a few mistakes in your code:

1. You're calling a function before it is defined. Calling `counterA` before it's defined.
2. You've to reset the counter `num1` in the `for` loop

Possible option to make your code to work:

1. Remove 
   `var num1 ;
   counterA(num1);
   var total=0;`
2. Replace `for (num1 = num11; ...` with `for(var num1 = num11; ...`

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<script>

function counterA(num11)
{
   var num1;
    for (num1 = num11; num1 <= 24; num1 += 5)
    {
        alert(num1);
        counterB(num1);
    }
}

function counterB(num11)
{
    counterA(num11 * 3);
}
</script>

<body>

<button onclick="counterA(1)">Try it</button>

</body>

</html>
```

This is giving me output as 1, 3, 9, 14, 19, 24, 8, 24, 13, 18, 23, 6, 18, 23, 11, 16 and 21.

Comment: Great. You can accept my answer if it helped you and you find the solution. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function counterA(num11){
        for (var num1 = num11; num1 <= 24; num1 += 5) {
            alert(num1);
            counterA(num1*3);
        }
    }
</script>

<body>
    <button onclick="counterA(1)">Try me</button>
</body>

</html>
```